# Perform an action after returning from a getter

Tags: javascript, return, getter-setter

I have a function that sets a getter and setter on an object or array.
My problem is that if the set value is an object I cannot detect its internal changes but only when it is accessed assuming it is accessed through the getter. At the moment the getter returns the object however I want to perform an action after returning the getter wether it was changed or not.

My code at the moment:

```
set = function(obj, i, val) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, i, {
        set(newVal) {
            val = newVal
            // react to changes 
            insert(val, i)
        },
        get() {
            return val
            //I want this to run after the object was accessed and possibly changed
            if (typeof val == "object") {
                insert(val, i)
            }
        },
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true
    })
}
```

I have thought of one solution which is setTimeout however if the setter and getter are deleted the setTimeout could cause unwanted behaviour and I would rather the code remained synchronous.

The another idea I have considered is defining setters and getters on all of the objects properties however this would be expensive.

How can I solve this?

Comment: *"however if the setter and getter are deleted the setTimeout could cause unwanted behaviour"* Huh?

Comment: You could either freeze the object or use a library like Immutablejs, so that the only way the object can be updated is by setting it again.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If they are redefined or removed with the delete keyword then the setTimeouts function would still fire and have access to the object

Comment: I'm attempting to recreate Ng-repeat without angularjs

Answer (score 1):

> I have thought of one solution which is setTimeout...

That's how you'd do it, that or `Promise.resolve().then(...)`.

> ...and I would rather the code remained synchronous.

It **can't** be synchronous. You can perform an action after the getter returns, or it can be synchronous. You can't have it both ways.

---

**That said**, there's no guarantee whatsoever that doing something asynchronous soon after the getter is used will detect anything done with the object. Consider:

```
var o = yourObject.theProperty;
setTimeout(function() {
    o.foo = "bar";
}, 6000);
```

Your getter on `theProperty` is executed on the first line. The object isn't changed until six seconds later.

If you want to detect *changes* to the object, then make all of its properties getter/setter properties that can't be reconfigured, and act on changes you see to them. (You might also use `Object.freeze` or `Object.seal` to prevent new properties being added.)

If you want the object to be able to have properties you haven't defined, but you still want to react to changes to them, you'll have to use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), with the concommitant performance hit. But for a known set of properties, non-configurable getter/setter properties do the job.